# Making joda.DateTime a searchable property in grails

Tags: datetime, grails, properties, searchable

I am using the joda time library in my grails project. 
I've installed the searchable plugin.
I have a few domains but the most important now :

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

class Entry {

     static searchable = {
     except = ['id', 'version']
     spellCheck "include"
     tags component: true

     title boost: 2.0
        dateCreated boost: 2.0
     }

 String title
 String content
 DateTime dateCreated
 DateTime lastUpdated

}
```

But on initialization I encounter the following error:

> Unable to map [Entry.dateCreated]. It does not appear to a suitable
>   'searchable property' (normally simple
>   types like Strings, Dates, Numbers,
>   etc), 'searchable reference' (normally
>   another domain class) or 'searchable
>   component' (normally another domain
>   class defined as a component, using
>   the 'embedded' declaration). Is it a
>   derived property (a getter method with
>   no equivalent field) defined with
>   'def'? Try defining it with a more
>   specific return type

My question:
Is it possible to make the dateCreated and/or lastUpdated properties searchable in grails?
If possible, how can this be done?

Thanks.

---

EDIT

If I was to define a custom converter in my config.groovy like so:

> Map compassSettings = [ 
>   'compass.converter. funkyConverter.type':'com.acme.compass.converter.FunkyConverter']

What is then defined in the FunkyConverter class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of compass that came with version 0.6 of Searchable (any maybe earlier versions) had some special case code in it (in class org.compass.core.converter.DefaultConverterLookup) for the org.joda.time.DateTime class. I can't speak directly to whether it works or not, but it looked like it would try to automatically make use of org.compass.core.converter.extended.DataTimeConverter included in Compass for the joda DateTime class.

However, for joda LocalDate and LocalTime classes, there was no built-in support. A recent bug fix to Searchable version 0.6.1 ( http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSEARCHABLE-28 ) along with the use of the registerClass configuration in Searchable.groovy shown below has fixed my "It does not appear to a suitable 'searchable property'..." problem that was occurring at application startup while domain objects were being instantiated in Bootstrap.groovy.

```
compassSettings = [
    "compass.converter.jodatime.type": "net.streamrecorder.web.converter.LocalTimeConverter",
    "compass.converter.jodatime.registerClass": "org.joda.time.LocalTime"
]
```

Note that net.streamrecorder.web.converter.LocalTimeConverter is my own creation. I modeled it after org.compass.core.converter.extended.DataTimeConverter. There is also a converter for LocalDate in this diff referenced from the GPSEARCHABLE-28 ticket: ( http://jira.grails.org/secure/attachment/15729/0001-Nasty-fixes-and-workarounds-for-adding-custom-compas.patch ) And of course, you still need to specify your converter for your domain member variable in your domain class as described here: ( http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+Converters )